# detect numbers in a list of strings and convert to int

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I have a list of strings:

```
strings = ['stability', 'of', 'the', 'subdural', 'hematoma', 'she', 'was', 'transferred', 'to', 'the', 'neurosciences', 'floor', 'on', '3', '8', 'after', '24', 'hours', 'of', 'close']
```

Whats the best way to iterate over the list, detect the numbers and change the type of the element to an int?

In this particular example, strings[13], strings[14] and strings[16], should be recognized as numbers and converted from type str to type int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `try/except` with a list comp, trying to cast to `int` and catching any `ValueErrors` just returning each element in the `except` when you do:

```
def cast(x):
    try: 
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
strings[:] =  [cast(x) for x in strings]
```

output:

```
['stability', 'of', 'the', 'subdural', 'hematoma', 'she', 'was', 
'transferred', 'to', 'the', 'neurosciences', 'floor', 'on', 3, 8, 
'after', 24, 'hours', 'of', 'close']
```

If you only had positive integers you could use `str.isdigit`:

```
strings[:] =  [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in strings]
```

The output would be the same but isdigit would not work for any negative numbers or `"1.0"` etc.. Using `strings[:] = ...` just means we change the original object/list.